# how to mask members in a union

Tags: c

i have a union

```
union filter_row
  {
        MAC_Filter MAC;
        IP_Filter IP;
        TCP_Filter TCP;
        UDP_Filter UDP;
        ICMP_Filter ICMP;
        ARP_Filter ARP;
  };
```

The members of this union are structure....how to mask the members of structures... Do I have to initialize them to all 1's initially???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to use to code tags to organize code in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is an international community. For many of us, English is not their first language. You might want to formulate your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

All members of a union share the same storage space, enough to accommodate the alignment and size of the largest and most restrictive of the members. Normally, you'd also require a member in the structure to indicate what union member to use.